# Changing the sound being played

Tags: android, eclipse

There are two sounds sound1 and sound2, i want to start a sound by pressing the button btnSTART, while the sound is being played the other button gets pressed (btn2) and the sound changes to sound2. How can i achieve this.

I am trying the following approach:

```
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button btnSTART = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button btnSTOP = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnSTOP.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.pause();
            }
        });

        btnSTART.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.start();
                mp.setLooping(true);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.light_switch_off);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.light_switch_on);
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

btn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button3:
        // Play voicefile
        if(mp != null) {
          mp.stop();
          mp.release();                 
        } else
          mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.light_switch_off);

        mp.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button4:
        // Stop MediaPlayer
        if(mp != null) {
          mp.stop();
          mp.release();                 
        } else
          mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.light_switch_on);

        mp.start(); 
        break;
    }
}
```